# Problema con efecto Hover con CSS en HTML

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema con el efecto **`:hover`** utilizado en el lenguaje de CSS para dar estilo a un elemento.

Resulta que tengo un botón que debe cambiar de color cada vez que se pasa el mouse sobre el mismo, con el efecto **`:hover`** le establecí un tiempo de **3 segundos** de duración que demora en cambiar el color de fondo **pero no lo toma**, **lo hace instantáneo**.

Dejo el botón que tengo:

```css
.btn_login{

        border-color: #2AFF00;
        border-style: ridge;
        border-radius: 50px;
        border-width: 7px;
        box-shadow: -5px 10px 60px -10px white inset;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(165, 255, 147,1) 0%, rgba(32, 205, 0,1) 52%, rgba(105, 255, 47,1) 100%);

        width: 35%;
        height: 45px;
        font-size: 14pt;
        color: white;

        
        -webkit-transition-delay: 3s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 3s;
        -ms-transition-duration: 3s;
        -o-transition-duration: 3s;
        
        outline-style: none !important;
   }
   
   .btn_login:hover{

        box-shadow: -5px 10px 60px -10px white inset;
        color: white;

        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(115, 173, 103,1) 0%, rgba(22, 125, 0,1) 52%, rgba(55, 155, 17,1) 100%);
        
        -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 3s;
        -ms-transition-duration: 3s;
        -o-transition-duration: 3s;
   }
```

```html
<form action="#" metod="POST">
<br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn_login">
</form>
```

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que me tome el tiempo de duración que le establecí, o en cambio obligar al navegador a que lo tome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes mal escrito el **`CSS`**, prueba con el siguiente código y después resuelve el tema del color.

```css
.btn_login {
        width: 35%;
        height: 45px;
        font-size: 14pt;
        color: white;
   }
   .btn_login:hover {
        color: blue;
        transition: all 3.0s ease-in !important;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
  <input type="submit" class="btn_login">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esto es lo que intenté, estás llamando algunas propiedades dos veces en el hover, no es necesario que se ejecuten si son las mismas, según entiendo `transition-delay` no soporta `linear-gradient`, así que lo reemplacé con un filtro que da un resultado similar.

```css
.btn_login{

        border-color: #2AFF00;
        border-style: ridge;
        border-radius: 50px;
        border-width: 7px;
        box-shadow: -5px 10px 60px -10px white inset;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(165, 255, 147,1) 0%, rgba(32, 205, 0,1) 52%, rgba(105, 255, 47,1) 100%);

        width: 35%;
        height: 45px;
        font-size: 14pt;
        color: white;
        
         transition-duration: .5s;
        -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
        -ms-transition-duration: .5s;
        -o-transition-duration: .5s;
        
        outline-style: none !important;
   }
   
   .btn_login:hover{

        filter: brightness(80%);
        transition-delay: 3s;
   }
```

```html
<form action="#" metod="POST">
<br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn_login">
</form>
```

Comment: Es extraño que no soporte `linear-gradient` si antes funcionaba. Además aquello me oscurece el botón, y yo solo le quiero **'cambiar'** el color.

Comment: Te puede servir esta información al respecto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6542623/9609518

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que poner todas las propìedades relativas a la transition en `.btn_login`, no en `.btn_login:hover` y poner tambien un filter en `.btn_login` porque si no no hay una transicion real de un estado a otro (tal como lo tenias, cuando no es hover no existe ni el estado ni la transition)
Debes tener claro que si pones el filter (o lo que sea que quieras animar) solo en hover no es posible animarlo, porque no se puede animar de "no existir" a "existir", sino que hay que animar de "pasar de tal estado" a "tal estado"

```css
.btn_login{

        border-color: #2AFF00;
        border-style: ridge;
        border-radius: 50px;
        border-width: 7px;
        box-shadow: -5px 10px 60px -10px white inset;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(165, 255, 147,1) 0%, rgba(32, 205, 0,1) 52%, rgba(105, 255, 47,1) 100%);

        width: 35%;
        height: 45px;
        font-size: 14pt;
        color: white;
        
         transition-duration: .5s;
        -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
        -ms-transition-duration: .5s;
        -o-transition-duration: .5s;
        transition-delay: 3s;
        outline-style: none !important;
        filter: none;
   }
   
   .btn_login:hover{

        filter: brightness(80%);

   }
```

```html
<form action="#" metod="POST">
<br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn_login">
</form>
```

Comment: Eso funciona bien, pero lo que busco es cambiarle el color.

Comment: Perdona, creo que he copiado el codigo de una respuesta en vez de tu pregunta, pero de todas formas el concepto es el mismo y no deberias tener problema en adaptarlo:
sin :hover: todas las propiedades de transition (incluido transition-delay) y el estado inicial
con :hover: solo el estado final